# Inheriting without arguments

Tags: scala, inheritance, case

I'm new to Scala and trying to employ the following inheritance:

```
abstract class Command(arg: Any)

case object Help extends Command // <---- Ok
```

But if I replace it with this:

```
abstract class Command(arg: Option[Any])

case object Help extends Command // <---- Fail
```

Why? Why is it working in the first example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first case is accepted by the compiler because it adapts the constructor argument to be `()`, i.e., the single instance of the `Unit` type:

```
$ scala -Xlint:adapted-args
Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> abstract class Command(arg: Any)
defined class Command

scala> case object Help extends Command
<console>:12: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () is deprecated: leaky (Object-receiving) target makes this especially dangerous.
        signature: Command(arg: Any): Command
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: new Command((): Unit)
       case object Help extends Command
                                ^
defined object Help
```

As you can see, this line:

```
case object Help extends Command
```

Has been rewritten by the compiler to be:

```
case object Help extends Command(())
```

That is, it passes `()` as the constructor argument, which is fine, because the argument is meant to be of type `Any`, and `Unit` satisfies that constraint.

However, in the second case, the constructor argument is of type `Option`, and `Unit` won't satisfy that constraint, so the compiler can't magically fill in the constructor argument.

In any case, it's better to disable this magic behaviour altogether by using the scalac option `-Yno-adapted-args`.